# Color changing working on Firefox but not IE or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

I am having the hardest time figuring out why this will not work on chrome or IE but works great in firefox. Essentially I have a nav bar that I was highlighting the link that was clicked on until another link was clicked

Here is my JS function:

```
function updateObjectIframe(which){
    document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = '<'+'object id="foo" style="height:100%;width:100%;" name="foo" type="text/html" data="'+which.href+'"><\/object>';
    var Elements = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
    Array.prototype.filter.call(Elements, function(Element){
       Element.style = "background: #F0E68C;color: black;";
    });
    which.style = "background: #333; color: #fff;";
}
```

My nav bar looks like the following. The pages get loaded into the the id "one".

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="one" style="height:95%;width:100%;">
    <object id="foo" name="foo">

    </object>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: closing `<ul>` is not really closing (missing `/`) - could that be it?

Comment: No sorry that was a typo when I transferred it here. :(

Comment: I am, that's why I'm going through each element in that array and setting the bg and color in each. Then I am setting the one I just clicked on to a different color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try rewriting this using normal JavaScript techniques. You're always safest if you avoid anything clever. The following has the expected (or what I infer to be the expected) visual effect in Chrome and IE9. Your odd looping construct worked in both of them, but the conventional `for` loop is more clear. What failed was assigning a string to the style property. That looks to be a non-portable Firefox extension.

```
function updateObjectIframe(which){
    document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = '<'+'object id="foo" style="height:100%;width:100%;" name="foo" type="text/html" data="'+which.href+'"><\/object>';
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
    for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
         var element = elements[i];
         element.style.background = '#F0E68C'
         element.style.color = 'black';
    }
    which.style.background = '#333';
    which.style.color = '#fff';
}
```

UPDATE

`document.getElementsByClassName()` appears not to have been supported by IE prior to IE9. And that's why everybody loves jQuery so much.

Also, a somewhat cleaner and definitely more hip way to do this might be to set up two CSS styles in a `style` tag: One for the "active" button, one for "inactive" buttons. Then you'd change the elements' [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) properties, and use a different way to collect the "button" elements (because they'll have different classes now, and `getElementsByClassName` is non-portable too):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function updateObjectIframe(which){
        document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = '<'+'object id="foo" style="height:100%;width:100%;" name="foo" type="text/html" data="'+which.href+'"><\/object>';
        var elements = menu.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
            elements[i].className = 'button';
        }
        which.className = 'selected-button';
    } 
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#menu a.button{
    background-color: #F0E68C;
    color: black;
}
#menu a.selected-button
{
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You're welcome! But see my update about older versions of IE.

Comment: Im glad you posed that I ended up doing it that way and was just logging in to post it myself!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the individual components of the style when changing it in javascript. Like this:

```
...
Element.style.background = "#F0E68C";
Element.style.color = "black";
...
which.style.background = "#333"
which.style.color = "#fff";
...
```

Answer (score -1):

just use something like so:

```
onlick="$(".classWhichAllYourLinksHave").style("background","WhatEverYouUse")this.style = "background: #F0E68C;color: black;""
```

instead of

```
onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;"
```

or call a function